# Show that the Ennerper's surface is conformally parametrized.

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

Differential Geometry by Pressley (problem 6.3.2 second edition):

"Show that the *Ennerper's surface* $\pmb\sigma(u,v)=(u-u^3/3+uv^2, v-v^3/3+vu^2, u^2-v^2)$ is conformally parametrized."

I have computed the first fundamental form of the surface to be $(1+u^2+v^2)^2(du^2+dv^2)$. But I don't know what to compare it to, to show it's proportional.
Pressley has answers at the back, and he says it's a multiple of $du^2+dv^2$. That is the fundamental form of the plane, so why is he comparing it to the plane? How do we know what to compare it to, when we are given only one surface patch?

Comment: That's the definition.

Comment: Ah you're right. I completely missed that. It's presented as a Corollary, which I skipped. I am new to this site. How do I close the question? Do I leave it like this? Do you tell the user to write the answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: I think there's an option that you can delete the question, just above the comments section.

Comment: Yeah but then you wont get the upvote point or someone else might have the same problem will never see it, no?

Comment: If you want, you can self  answer it, by for example stating that corollary in the book. That sort of finish the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to John Ma, I found that it says in the book as part of a Corollary (p.136), that a surface patch $\pmb\sigma(u,v)$ is conformal if and only if its first fundamental form is $\lambda(du^2+dv^2)$ for some smooth function $\lambda(u,v)$.